# How to create sprite surface like in "cham cham"

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

My question maybe a bit too broad but i am going for the concept. How can i create surface as they did in "Cham Cham" app

https://itunes.apple.com/il/app/cham-cham/id760567889?mt=8.

I got most of the stuff done in the app but the surface change with user touch is quite different. You can change its altitude and it grows and shrinks. How this can be done using sprite kit what is the concept behind that can anyone there explain it a bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here comes the answer from Cham Cham developers :)

Let me split the explanation into different parts:

Note: As the project started quite a while ago, it is implemented using pure OpenGL. The SpiteKit implementation might differ, but you just need to map the idea over to it.

**Defining the ground**

The ground is represented by a set of points, which are interpolated over using [Hermite Spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation). Basically, the game uses a bunch of points defining the surface, and a set of points between each control one, like the below:

[image]

The red dots are control points, and eveyrthing in between is computed used the metioned Hermite interpolation. The green points in the middle have nothing to do with it, but make the whole thing look like boobs :)

You can choose an arbitrary amount of steps to make your boobs look as smooth as possible, but this is more to do with performance.

**Controlling the shape**

All you need to do is to allow the user to move the control points (or some of them, like in Cham Cham; you can define which range every point could move in etc). Recomputing the interpolated values will yield you an changed shape, which remains smooth at all times (given you have picked enough intermediate points).

**Texturing the thing**

Again, it is up to you how would you apply the texture. In Cham Cham, we use one big texture to hold the background image and recompute the texture coordinates at every shape change. You could try a more sophisticated algorithm, like squeezing the texture or whatever you found appropriate.

As for the surface texture (the one that covers the ground – grass, ice, sand etc) – you can just use the thing called [Triangle Strips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip), with "bottom" vertices sitting at every interpolated point of the surface and "top" vertices raised over (by offsetting them against "bottom" ones in the direction of the normal to that point).

**Rendering it**

The easiest way is to utilize some tesselation library, like [libtess](https://github.com/memononen/libtess2). What it will do it covert you boundary line (composed of interpolated points) into a set of triangles. It will preserve texture coordinates, so that you can just feed these triangles to the renderer.

**SpriteKit note**

Unfortunately, I am not really familiar with SpriteKit engine, so cannot guarantee you will be able to copy the idea over one-to-one, but please feel free to comment on the challenging aspects of the implementation and I will try to help.